# Publish file content to service bus from CI pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In my CI pipeline I am trying to publish message to service bus and its working when its just some hardcoded text or variables, here Using "PublishToAzureServiceBus" task .
But problem is when trying to a read file from repository and then publish that to service bus.

I have tried using read file using scripting language and put to variable but its not able to work as variable is not storing big json file.
Is there any way to read file directly when publishing message to service bus.

Below is sample code snippet for debugging

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: ProjectName
  displayName: Project Name
  type: string
  default: DevOpsDemo
- name: repoName
  displayName: repo Name
  type: string
  default: ProjectCode
- name: branchRef
  displayName: Branch Name
  type: string
  default: main
variables:
 - name: jobStatus
   value: "Failed"
 - name: projectFile
   value: ""
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  displayName: Stage 1
  jobs:
  - job: CheckOutRepo
    displayName: CheckOut-Repo Display
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "Checkout for " ${{ parameters.ProjectName}} : ${{ parameters.repoName}} : ${{ parameters.branchRef}}
      name: PrintMessage
    - checkout: git://${{ parameters.ProjectName}}/${{ parameters.repoName}}@refs/heads/${{ parameters.branchRef}}
      name: Checkout
    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline'
        script: |
          import json
          import requests
          f = open('project-release.json')
          projectFile = json.load(f)
          print(projectFile)
          f.close()
          print("Afterclosing")
          print(projectFile)
    - script: |
        echo "Project release file" $(cat project-release.json)
      name: TestPrint
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: 'services'
        Contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      name: CopyFiles
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
      name: PublishArtifacts
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=jobStatus]Success"
      name: setVar
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=jobStatus;isOutput=true]$(jobStatus)"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectFile;isOutput=true]$(cat project-release.json)"
      name: SetStatus
      condition: always()
- stage: Stage2
  displayName: Stage 2
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    pool: server
    variables:
      jobStatus: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.CheckOutRepo.outputs['SetStatus.jobStatus'] ]
      projectFile: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.CheckOutRepo.outputs['SetStatus.projectFile'] ]
    steps:
      - task: PublishToAzureServiceBus@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'SBConnection'
          messageBody: |
            {
            "Status": "$(jobStatus)",
            "BuildID": "$(build.buildid)",
            "BuildNumber":"$(build.buildnumber)",
            "projectFile":$(cat project-release.json)
            }
          signPayload: false
          waitForCompletion: false
        condition: always()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this by using setvariable in bash script as below

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Stage1
  displayName: Stage 1
  jobs:
  - job: CheckOutRepo
    displayName: CheckOut-Repo Display
    steps:
    - checkout: git://${{ parameters.ProjectName}}/${{ parameters.repoName}}@refs/heads/${{ parameters.branchRef}}
      name: Checkout
    - bash: |
        data=$(cat project-release.json)
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=jobStatus;isOutput=true]$(jobStatus)"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=data;isOutput=true]"$data
      name: SetStatus
      condition: always()
- stage: Stage2
  displayName: Stage 2
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    pool: server
    variables:
      jobStatus: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.CheckOutRepo.outputs['SetStatus.jobStatus'] ]
      projectFile: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.CheckOutRepo.outputs['SetStatus.data'] ]
    steps:
      - task: PublishToAzureServiceBus@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'SBConnection'
          messageBody: |
            {
            "Status": "$(jobStatus)",
            "BuildID": "$(build.buildid)",
            "BuildNumber":"$(build.buildnumber)",
            "projectFile":$(projectFile)
            }
          signPayload: false
          waitForCompletion: false
        condition: always()
```